# Jquery - Convert string to reg exp object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, expression

My regular expression is `/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/` and in html I added it as a hidden element with the value of the element set to the above pattern

When I do this:

```js
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/ 
var text = $(this).val()
```

and then test with `regex.test(text)` it works fine.

but when I assign regex like this:

```
var regex = $("#m"+id).val() // (my hidden element)
```

then it doesnt work. I have tried assigning it using new RegExp as well but also not working.I think it's doing it because it's returning the value as a string from `$("#m"+id).val()` (I am getting the right value returned here), but not sure what to parse it to.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build regexp from string, then use Constructor of RegExp class, it takes string without slashes, so you should remove them. `.slice(1, -1)` removes first and last charecters. Try to use this:

```
var regex = new RegExp($("#m"+id).val().slice(1, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var regex = new RegExp($("#m"+id).val())
```

Answer (score 0):

The slashes at the beginning and the end are only used when it is a regex literal. Remove them to get the actual regular expression, then you can use `new RegExp(str)` to turn the string into a regex object.